# What is the fastest possible way to write below code in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the fastest possible way to write below code C#? I tried many ways but unable to improve performance any solution will be highly appreciated.

This ToNumber is called 1000 in for loop which takes lot of times to process.

```
     public static Dictionary<string, string> demoText = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                {
                                        {"", "09"},
                                        {"ff","19"},
                                        {"fdffsdfd","29" },
                                        {"dfsdfsdfsd","39" },
                                        {"dfsdfsf","49" },
                                        {"dsdsdfs","95" },
                                        {"hjghjgh","79" },
                                        { "ghjghj","89"},
                                        {"hjghjgh","99" },
                                        {"hjghj","190" },
                                        {"ghjghj","191" },
                                        { "hjghj","12"},
                                        {"hghjg","133" },
                                        {"ghjghjgh","124" },
                                        {"hjghjgh","135" },
                                        {"jghjgh","196" },
                                        {"jjj","179" },
                                        {"ttt","198" },
                                        {"sdfsdf","199" },
                                        {"sdffs","290" },
                                        { "fsdfdf","291"},
                                        {"fsdkfhsdf","22" },
                                        { "fdfgdfgdfg","23"},
                                        { "fgdfgdfg","339"},
        
                                };
        
            private static Double ToNumber(string value, bool isScore)
            {
                var result = Double.MinValue;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    if (isScore)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            result = Double.Parse(DemoText[value.ToLowerInvariant()]);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            if (value.ToLowerInvariant().Equals("ttt")) result = 0.0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            result = Double.Parse(value.Replace("%", ""));
                        }
                        catch (Exception) { }
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
```

Comment: `.ToLowerInvariant()` - don't do this. Construct the dictionary with `StringComparer.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Also, check `if (value.ToLowerInvariant().Equals("ttt")) result = 0.0;` before your `Double.Parse`, not after failing to parse. And use `Double.TryParse` instead.

Comment: Also use `DemoText.TryGetValue(...)`.

Comment: I can't see the point in storing string values in the dictionary that you then have to parse. Store doubles

Comment: As for the %: is that always at the end? If the position of the % is predictable and at the start/end, there may be better ways to handle the middle - or, honestly, just have the dictionary always include the suffix, so: have both `"jjj"` and `"jjj%"` as keys with the same value (which I agree with @Caius: should be just `double`)

Comment: isn't `hjghjgh` added twice? Should the value for it be `79` or `99`? Same for the value `ghjghj`, and `hjghj`.

Comment: @Hrant I assume these are just sldkhglkjsfg overtypings to obscure real values like passwords/sales targets etc

Comment: If you want the *fastest*, turn the dictionary lookup into a hard coded FSM...

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment

```
        public static Dictionary<string, double> DemoText = new Dictionary<string, double>(StringComparer.InvariantIgnoreCase)
                            {
                                    {"", 9},
                                    {"ff",19},
                                    ...
                            };
    
        private static Double ToNumber(string value, bool isScore)
        {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    return Double.MinValue;

            
                if (isScore)
                {
                    if(DemoText.TryGetValue(value, out double x)
                    {
                        return x;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        return Double.MinValue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Double.TryParse(value.Replace("%", ""), out double x)
                    {
                        return x;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        return Double.MinValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Put `value` of `"ttt"` as `0.0` in the dictionary. Incorporate Marc's comment either by putting percent values in the dictionary or if the percent will only appear in certain places, consider eg `TrimEnd` rather than `Replace`

Avoid using exceptions for control flow; they're incredibly expensive especially if you're just throwing them way

Comment: I was about to add something very similar; nice job - one observation: in the original version, the code did not expect `ttt` in the "`isScore` is `false`" scenario, so you might need to special-case that

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that all the values are `int`s. I don't know why would you store them as a double, but whatever I think you have a reason for that.

I ran some benchmarks and your code took `~1400ms` for `100` iterations.

where this alternative takes `~200ms` for `1000000` iterations:

- First because we have not very large amount of data we can store them in a 2D array instead of dictionary. But let's take a look what we do in most common case: we're iterating over the `keys`. So it would be optimal to store them in `SoA` form for better CPU cache utilization:

```cs
public static string[] Texts = new string[]
{
    "", "ff", "fdffsdfd", "dfsdfsdfsd", "dfsdfsf", "dsdsdfs",
    "hjghjgh", "ghjghj", "hjghjgh", "hjghj", "ghjghj", "hjghj", "hghjg", "ghjghjgh", "hjghjgh",
            "jghjgh", "jjj", "ttt", "sdfsdf", "sdffs", "fsdfdf", "fsdkfhsdf", "fdfgdfgdfg", "fgdfgdfg"
};

public static double[] Values = new double[]
{
    9,
    19,
    29 ,
    39 ,
    49 ,
    95 ,
    79 ,
    89,
    99 ,
    190 ,
    191 ,
    12,
    133 ,
    124 ,
    135 ,
    196 ,
    179 ,
    198 ,
    199 ,
    290 ,
    291,
    22 ,
    23,
    339,
};
```

Now let's replace try catches with if's (notice try catch has 2 disadvantages: `A`:  The JIT compiler can not optimize the assembly code inside a try catch very well and `B`: If has lot less instructions than try catch).

```cs
private static double ToNumber(string value, bool isScore)
{
    var result = double.MinValue;
    var text   = value.ToLowerInvariant();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        if (isScore)
        {

            int i = 0;
            for (; i < Texts.Length; ++i)
                if (text == Texts[i])
                    return Values[i];

            if (text.Equals("ttt"))
                return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            double res;
            bool err;

            err = double.TryParse(value.Replace("%", ""), out res);
            if (!err)
                result = res;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm sure one can optimize even better using intrinsics or with any other additional information/context.